# Send all subdomains to a 404 directory with status of 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make it so that all sub-domains go to a 404 page, except for Admin:

```
# MAKE ALL OTHER SUB DOMAINS 404
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !^404/? [R=404,L]

# ALLOW ADMIN SUB DOMAIN AND SEND TRAFFIC TO SUB FOLDER
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !^admin/? admin%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

But the 404 doesn't work (it shows root content)... What have I done wrong?

It should be setting a status of 404 but loading the content from the 404 directory at the root level via the rewrite.

Comment: First of all, you need to switch the order of those rules around – you can not catch something more specific after something less specific. Secondly, `^\.example\.com$` is not “all other subdomains”, but would match `.example.com` only. And finally, flag `R` will always issue an external redirect – not sure if that’s really what you want.

Comment: What is the DNS configuration? For all these domains.  If these subdomains don't exist in DNS configuration, then they would never get to the server anyway.

Comment: @CBroe What would it be then?

Comment: @MikeBrant I use wildcard subdomains.

Comment: @Cameron Why?  Is the only subdomain your support is admin.domain.com. why handle any additional traffic only to give them a 404 error? You would probably be better off informing end client that the subdomain requested does not resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# ALLOW ADMIN SUB DOMAIN AND SEND TRAFFIC TO SUB FOLDER
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^admin/? admin%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

# MAKE ALL OTHER SUB DOMAINS 404
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|admin)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^404/ 404/ [L]
```

Comment: Does the 404, but doesn't load the 404 content at http://example.com/404,  perhaps I could use a 301 instead to achieve this?

Comment: Almost! If I load up: `http://nothing.example.com/` then it changes the url to `http://nothing.example.com/404` it shouldn't change the url (not add the 404 affix) but just load the content of the 404. Thanks.

Comment: By forwarding it is adding the 404 onto the url... it shouldn't be doing that as it should just be a rewrite and not a redirect. No other rules are there.

Comment: For example: http://test.camerondrysdale.com/ goes to http://test.camerondrysdale.com/404/ but it should just be loading the content of the 404 (which it does) but without altering that url to have the 404 within it.

Comment: In fact everything now redirects to that 404 (even the WWW and without WWW) so it's definitely not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73616/discussion-between-anubhava-and-cameron).